# Go pointer stored into non-Go memory

Tags: go, cgo

I've got a newbie CGO question I was wondering if someone could help me with. When running with GODEBUG set to cgocheck=2 my application crashes with the following

```
write of Go pointer 0xc0003b72c0 to non-Go memory 0x7fefa0016810
fatal error: Go pointer stored into non-Go memory
```

The code causing the issue is

```
cArray := C.malloc(C.size_t(len(fd.Faces)) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0))))
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cArray))
a := (*[1<<30 - 1]*C.struct_Box)(cArray)
for index, value := range fd.GetFaceRectangles() {
    box := &C.struct_Box{
        left: C.int(value.Min.X),
        top: C.int(value.Min.Y),
        right: C.int(value.Max.X),
        bottom: C.int(value.Max.Y),
    }
    a[index] = box
}
cBoxCount := C.int(len(fd.Faces))
ret := C.facerec_compute_multi(rec.ptr, cImgData, cLen,  &a[0], cBoxCount)
```

Specifically this row:

```
a[index] = box
```

I understand the memory for the array is allocated in C using malloc. I'm trying to add C Box to the array before passing it to a C function. Would the fix for this be for me to write a function in C which can receive the array and the items needed to create the struct and I do that part in C instead? I'm trying to minimise the number of calls to C so If I can create the array from Go that would be great. Really struggling with how to pass an array of data through to a function in C safely.

Comment: Not sure if I can formulate an answer yet as this is hard for me to test, but here are my thoughts: 1) try converting the `box` to an `unsafe.Pointer` or even `uintptr` before assigning it to `a[index]`. 2) You might also be able to build the entire array in Go and then convert it to an `uintptr` and pass that to C.

Comment: In case you haven't read this article yet: https://go101.org/article/unsafe.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've allocated C memory to hold many individual pointers.  Each individual pointer can be set to a separate value.  That's fine as far as it goes, but as you noted, the `a[index] = box` is a problem, because `box` itself holds a pointer to a Go-memory `C.struct_Box`.

> I'm trying to add C Box to the array before passing it to a C function.

To do that literally, you need a `C.malloc` call.  As written, you'll need one per `C.struct_Box` instance.

> Would the fix for this be for me to write a function in C which can receive the array and the items needed to create the struct and I do that part in C instead?

While you could try that, it seems ... suboptimal.

> I'm trying to minimise the number of calls to C so If I can create the array from Go that would be great. Really struggling with how to pass an array of data through to a function in C safely.

C is never really *safe*  but I suspect your best bet here is to make use of the way C implements "arrays", which is as a sort of poor-man's slice.  (Or, perhaps more accurately, a Go slice is a "C array" done right.)  Remember that a slice is implemented in Go as a three-element header:

- pointer to base of storage area;
- current length within storage area; and
- capacity of storage area

which can then hold some run-time computed number *n* of items of some type.  C's dynamic "arrays" work the same way, only without the safety of a proper slice header.

What this means is that you can write your C code—*provided* you have *control* of this C code—to take a pointer to a base of a storage area, and an `int` or `size_t` value that counts the number *n* of items in that area.  The signature of such a function is:

```
void f(T *base, size_t n);
```

where `n` is the number of items.  (Add a second `size_t` if appropriate, if you want to provide a capacity as well, though if the memory has capacity, and the function modifies it to contain a different number of items, then either the function must return the new number of items—i.e., `f` would not be `void`—or `n` itself has to be provided by reference or something along those lines.)

In this case, if you can arrange the C code to take a pointer to the first of `n` `struct Box`-es (instead of the first of `n` *pointers to* `struct Box`-es), you can allocate that in a single `C.malloc` call.

If you can't rework the C code, you're stuck with a minimum of two `C.malloc` calls.  You can, however, allocate all the `struct Box`es in one `C.malloc` again, and make them all adjacent—i.e., a C "array" / poor-man's-slice—and then make each pointer point to the next `struct Box`:

```golang
cArray := C.malloc(C.size_t(len(fd.Faces)) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0))))
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cArray))
cBoxes := C.malloc(C.size_t(len(fd.Faces)) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(C.struct_Box)))
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cBoxes))
a := (*[1<<30 - 1]*C.struct_Box)(cArray)
b := (*[1<<30 - 1]C.struct_Box)(cBoxes)
for index, value := range fd.GetFaceRectangles() {
    b[index] = C.struct_Box{
        left: C.int(value.Min.X),
        top: C.int(value.Min.Y),
        right: C.int(value.Max.X),
        bottom: C.int(value.Max.Y),
    }
    a[index] = &b[index]
}
cBoxCount := C.int(len(fd.Faces))
ret := C.facerec_compute_multi(rec.ptr, cImgData, cLen,  &a[0], cBoxCount)
```

(I've tried to keep the code structure as similar as possible here, and this is quite untested since I don't have some of the parts.)

Aside: you have `len(fd.Faces)` and `fd.GetFaceRectangles()` and the code here assumes that the number of iterations of a `for ... range fd.GetFaceRectangles()` is always `len(fd.Faces)`.  I'm calling this out because I have made the same assumption, without anything to back it other than your example.

Answer (score 0):

With some help on the Slack channel I ended up with this, just adding the struct directly instead of a pointer.

```
// Create an array in C
arr := C.malloc(C.size_t(len(fd.Faces)) * C.sizeof_Box)
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(arr))

var boxes []C.struct_Box
hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&boxes))
hdr.Data, hdr.Cap, hdr.Len = uintptr(arr), len(fd.Faces), len(fd.Faces)

for i, v := range fd.GetFaceRectangles() {
    boxes[i] = C.struct_Box{
        left: C.int(v.Min.X),
        top: C.int(v.Min.Y),
        right: C.int(v.Max.X),
        bottom: C.int(v.Max.Y),
    }
}
cBoxCount := C.int(len(fd.Faces))
ret := C.facerec_compute_multi(rec.ptr, cImgData, cLen, &(boxes[0]), cBoxCount)
```

Comment: FYI that's more or less the idea I was recommending: make a linear array of C "box" structs and fill them in. (I'd avoid the `reflect.SliceHeader` trick if possible too, but it's fine as is. The other construct has that weird `[1<<30]` or similar trick, so it's equally ugly.)